# GCE gcloud compute ssh creating users on demand

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

Using the `gcloud compute ssh [user@]host` command, the user gets created on-demand if it doesn't exists on the box yet. This can easily make a mess on the boxes by, say, forgetting to specify the correct user, or just mistyping the user, and end up with multiple unwanted ad-hoc `sudo`-enabled user accounts all over the place. Scale this to a team of GCE admins and it gets a LOT worse.

I naively expected `gcloud` commands executed under a specific GCE account to be somehow tied to a *preset* user for that account for it to be identifiable and traceable throughout the infrastructure. Is this not possible?

Maybe there's a way to set a user override for `gcloud`? I didn't find a setting for that yet, and it still wouldn't prevent the mess-up, just less typing and related errors.

I understand that `gcloud compute ssh` might not be for general usage, but it still has to be used to some extent, even if only for some initial setup. How can it be made safe, predictable and repeatable regarding users?

Comment: Care to elaborate on downvote? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be controlled by adding [User Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/user-accounts/) to your instances. Once the setup is done, you can connect to your instance with gcloud using a user account by running the following command and replacing INSTANCE with the instance name and USERNAME with the account username:

```
   $ gcloud beta compute ssh USERNAME@INSTANCE
```

A username is recommended but not required, and if not provided, **gcloud assumes that the user is the email account authenticated with gcloud**.

Comment: Thanks, works almost as needed, except for the beta feature drawbacks - requires beta tooling, is clunky to use and setup, requires Debian/Ubuntu. Hence it's more of a workaround for the time being.